# Yii uploaded blob image is not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, image, yii, blob

In my MySQL database I have a row with a LongBlob type called `photo`.

In my form I used the `fileField` provided by Yii so it looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'photo'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'photo'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'photo'); ?>
</div>
```

I have 2 databases for security reasons (1 for backend and another for front) so the code I use to display it looks like this:

```
db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hygeia_master"); //keep your db name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM about_photo order by datetime desc limit 1";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['photo'] ).'"/>'; ?>
```

Then it only displays this:

[image]

But whenever I upload from phpMyAdmin itself it displays the correct image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `header()` before display image.

First you need to create action in `siteController`

Like this,

```
public function actionloadImage()
{
        db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hygeia_master"); //keep your db name
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM about_photo order by datetime desc limit 1";
        $sth = $db->query($sql);
        $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        print $result['photo']; 
        exit(); 
}
```

And in view file use this

```
echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/site/loadImage'), 'No Image', array('width'=>80,'height'=>70));
```